# ROS2 Dynamic messages template

Tags: c++, ros2

I have a question regarding ROS2 messages or possibly just standard C++, maybe one of you have tried something similar before, or can tell me that what I am trying to accomplish won't work.

What I'm trying to create is a library that I can use to quickly create a ROS2 Node, dynamically add publishers and/or subscribers, depending on the situation, before starting the node.
The problem I'm facing is that ROS2 uses message types like `std_msgs::msg::String`. Example source can be found on [github](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/minimal_subscriber/member_function.cpp).
The source uses the following code to create a subscriber:

```
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10, std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
```

I would like to create a function that can create a subscriber using a given message type i.e.:

```
void createListener(std::string topicName, 'messagetype')
{
    auto subscription_ = this->create_subscription<'messagetype'>(topicname, 10, [this]{}, this, _1));
    //adding the created subscriber to a list is already done
}
```

This would allow me to use the same function while still being able to use different messages like:

```
nav_msgs::msg::Path
geometry_msgs::msg::Point
```

without having to create a new function for every message type.
I can't seem to find the template type that is used in the `create_subscribtion<>()` function, all I can find is that each message creates its own type.
`std_msgs::msg::String` would return the `std_msgs::msg::String_<std::allocator<void>>` type.

Is there a way that i can make this work?

Comment: I did something tangential, https://github.com/klintan/rosbag2_nodejs/blob/master/src/rosbag2_deserialize.cpp perhaps that will get you started?

Answer (score 2):

You could use templates here right, by doing the following:

```
template <typename MsgType>
void createListener(std::string topicName)
{
    auto subscription_ = this->create_subscription<MsgType>(topicname, 10, [this]{}, this, _1));
    //adding the created subscriber to a list is already done
}
```

This function can then be called, for example by:

```
createListener<nav_msgs::msg::Path>("topicName")
```